# How to transfer ios app with subscriptions?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, transfer, app-transfer

I can't transfer my app with auto-renewable subscription, but i have generated shared secret key.
What must I do to transfer my app?

Screenshots proof:

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPrd2.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL2RY.png)

Comment: Hm, I might be wrong. But could you change the "auto renewing" setting? So it will NOT be auto renewing anymore? Then the criteria would be finally met

Comment: Have you tried regnerating the share key?  Otherwise, you should contact Apple developer support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create new Shared Secret Key for the application.